# Переход к меню после проверки ID при написании tg бота

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot

Подскажите кто-нибудь пожалуйста, как сделать так, что бы после проверки ID бот автоматом выводил на приветственное меню с Reply кнопками, а не писал что доступ разрешён

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    adm = [мой ID]
    if message.chat.id not in adm:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доступ воспрещён')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доступ разрешён')
        
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton('кнопка 1')
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton('кнопка 2')
    item3 = types.KeyboardButton('кнопка 3')
    item4 = types.KeyboardButton('кнопка 4')

markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Приветствую, {0.first_name}'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup = markup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может так?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    adm = [мой ID]
    if message.chat.id not in adm:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доступ запрещён')
    else:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.KeyboardButton('кнопка 1')
        item2 = types.KeyboardButton('кнопка 2')
        item3 = types.KeyboardButton('кнопка 3')
        item4 = types.KeyboardButton('кнопка 4')
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3, item4)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Приветствую, {message.from_user.first_name}', reply_markup=markup)
```